# Issue in Get List named With contains # using Rest Service API

Tags: rest, custom-list, url, sharepoint-hosted-app, encoding

**I have a List named 'KKR Jobs #'. And I am try to Get that list in my Sharepoint Hosted App Using Rest Service Call Like**

```
var lName = 'KKR Jobs #';
     executor.executeAsync(
    {
        url:
            "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + encodeURIComponent(lName) + "')/fields/getbytitle('Job Status')?$select=Choices",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: successHandlerStatus,
        error: errorHandler
    }
);
```

- Its Fetching all Lists Except this List named 'KKR Jobs #' in my Site
  Collection.
- It Gives Error like Page Not Found in Browser Check like http://*****:11508/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('KKR Jobs #').
- **Any Issue in naming of List which contains # symbol.**

i Appreciate any suggestions and Answers..!!!!!!

Comment: try var lname='KKR%20Jobs%20%23'

Comment: and why you have a space after lName in encodeURIComponent?? Check that

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the items with guid of the list instead of title

e.g http://****/_api/web/Lists(guid`'<your list id>')`/items